# Want to call different macros based on argument size

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

My story is I want to assemble a static byte array from various of integers of different sizes.

Therefor, I have three macros as

```
#define CONV_BYTE(x)        (uint8_t)(x)
#define CONV_WORD(x)        (uint16_t)(x) & 0xff, (uint16_t)(x) >> 8 & 0xff
#define CONV_LONG(x)        (uint32_t)(x) & 0xff, (uint32_t)(x) >> 8 & 0xff, \
        (uint32_t)(x) >> 16 & 0xff, (uint32_t)(x) >> 24 & 0xff
```

They are used as

```
const uint8_t const _name[] = {CONV_BYTE(byte_arg), CONV_WORD(word_arg), CONV_LONG(long_arg)};
```

Is there any way to have a one macro for all length types of argument, that chooses the corresponding macro by the size of argument?

As far as I understand that, sizeof() seems a dead end. Is there any trick on that?

Comment: How would the compiler know which input type you want? And note your macros will generate conversion warnings if properly enabled.

Comment: [`_Generic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic)

Comment: @Leandros I don't think you can use `,` in the `_Generic` expression part. (I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: @Leandros Thanks for the suggestion, As for as I understand, _Generic words only on values like function pointer, but not expression ?

Comment: @TanXinyu Nope, `_Generic` works for any expression (except for the comma operator).

Answer (score 0):

We can't use _Generic, because each element has to expand to a constant number of elements/commas. _Generic won't help us - _Generic is evaluated by the compiler.

However, there is an edge that we can use - array index initializers. That means that we have to traverse all elements in one macro - because we have to know from which array index to start the next element from, so we have to know the context, i.e. previous elements.

The array index initializer elements have to be constant - 4 - from each element after expansion, because preprocessor does not know about types. However, I can also use that array index initializers are processed *in order*. So with proper indexes, the previous once with the same index will be ignored.

This means that for uint8_t I can generate four times `[0] = stuff` with the last "stuff" being actually relevant. For `uint6_t` I can generate `[0]=stuff,[1]=stuff,[0]=stuff,[1]=stuff,` and the last stuffs are relevant.

The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define CONV_VAL(start, v, idx) \
        [start + idx % sizeof(v)] = (uint8_t)((uint32_t)(v) >> (8 * idx) & 0xff),
#define CONV_1(start, v) \
        CONV_VAL(start, v, 3) \
        CONV_VAL(start, v, 2) \
        CONV_VAL(start, v, 1) \
        CONV_VAL(start, v, 0)
#define CONV_2(start, a, ...) \
        CONV_1(start, a) \
        CONV_1(start + sizeof(a), __VA_ARGS__)
#define CONV_3(start, a, ...) \
        CONV_1(start, a) \
        CONV_2(start + sizeof(a), __VA_ARGS__)
#define CONV_N(_3,_2,_1,N,...)  CONV##N
#define CONV(...)  CONV_N(__VA_ARGS__,_3,_2,_1)(0, __VA_ARGS__)

#define MK16(a, b)  (b<<8|a)
#define MK32(a, b, c, d)  (MK16(a, b)|MK16(c, d)<<16)
static const uint8_t byte_arg = 'I';
static const uint16_t word_arg = MK16(' ', 'r');
static const uint32_t long_arg = MK32('u', 'l', 'e', '!');

static const uint8_t name[] = {
    CONV(
        byte_arg,
        word_arg,
        long_arg
    )
};

int main() {
    printf("%.*s", (int)(sizeof(name)/sizeof(*name)), (char*)name);
}
```

Outputs: `I rule!`.

The `name` initializer looks like this:

```
static const uint8_t name[] = {
    [0 + 3 % sizeof(byte_arg)] =
        (uint8_t)((uint32_t)(byte_arg) >> (8 * 3) & 0xff),
    [0 + 2 % sizeof(byte_arg)] =
        (uint8_t)((uint32_t)(byte_arg) >> (8 * 2) & 0xff),
    [0 + 1 % sizeof(byte_arg)] =
        (uint8_t)((uint32_t)(byte_arg) >> (8 * 1) & 0xff),
    [0 + 0 % sizeof(byte_arg)] =
        (uint8_t)((uint32_t)(byte_arg) >> (8 * 0) & 0xff),
    [0 + sizeof(byte_arg) + 3 % sizeof(word_arg)] =
        (uint8_t)((uint32_t)(word_arg) >> (8 * 3) & 0xff),
    [0 + sizeof(byte_arg) + 2 % sizeof(word_arg)] =
        (uint8_t)((uint32_t)(word_arg) >> (8 * 2) & 0xff),
    [0 + sizeof(byte_arg) + 1 % sizeof(word_arg)] =
        (uint8_t)((uint32_t)(word_arg) >> (8 * 1) & 0xff),
    [0 + sizeof(byte_arg) + 0 % sizeof(word_arg)] =
        (uint8_t)((uint32_t)(word_arg) >> (8 * 0) & 0xff),
    [0 + sizeof(byte_arg) + sizeof(word_arg) + 3 % sizeof(long_arg)] =
        (uint8_t)((uint32_t)(long_arg) >> (8 * 3) & 0xff),
    [0 + sizeof(byte_arg) + sizeof(word_arg) + 2 % sizeof(long_arg)] =
        (uint8_t)((uint32_t)(long_arg) >> (8 * 2) & 0xff),
    [0 + sizeof(byte_arg) + sizeof(word_arg) + 1 % sizeof(long_arg)] =
        (uint8_t)((uint32_t)(long_arg) >> (8 * 1) & 0xff),
    [0 + sizeof(byte_arg) + sizeof(word_arg) + 0 % sizeof(long_arg)] =
        (uint8_t)((uint32_t)(long_arg) >> (8 * 0) & 0xff),
};
```

The `&0xff` or `(uint8_t)` cast could be removed, it is converted to `uint8_t` anyway.

One would expand `CONV_N` with more cases to handle more arguments. `CONV_1` should be expanded to 8 elements to handle `uint16_t`. Elements in `CONV_1` have to be in reverse order - the last one counts for `uint8_t`, last two count for `uint16_t`, etc.